# Superset - get custom element from JWT

Tags: flask, jinja2, apache-superset, flask-login

In the jinja templating there are functions like `current_username()` or `current_user_id()`, which return the username or the user id of the logged in user, respectively. In my context, I have a field called "customer_cluster", which is part of the JWT. I need to access this "customer_cluster" value for the security setting, so that evey user only sees the data for his cluster.
I have come so far using `JINJA_CONTEXT_ADDONS`:

```
from superset.extensions import appbuilder

def customer_cluster():

    user_info = appbuilder.sm.oauth_remotes['myoauth'].get('https://www.myoauth/sts/connect/userinfo')           
    me = user_info.json()
    return me['customer_cluster']
        
JINJA_CONTEXT_ADDONS = {
'customer_cluster': customer_cluster
}
```

But I get the error message: `Failed to execute query '129' - 'select "{{customer_cluster()}}"': missing_token:`
I guess the this token refers to what I have provided as `OAUTH_PROVIDERS` in `superset_config_docker.py`? But where and in which form should I provide it?